# Programming in c using cygwin

Tags: c, cygwin

I was planning to program in c using cygwin on windows. Does this have any performance drawbacks when compared to using gcc in ubuntu?

Comment: cygwin is huge and in my experience slow.  If possible, its better to write your program under linux, and later get it building correctly under cygwin/minsys on windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used Cygwin on Windows 7 and Windows 2008 R2 for C development.  The experience was painful: not only slow, but I [never did](https://superuser.com/questions/288798/multi-term-in-emacs-under-cygwin-doesnt-correctly-identify-terminal-type) manage to get my preferred editor (Emacs) working properly in Cygwin.

You could try a live distro of Linux that you could boot from a USB memory stick.  That way you could program in C to your heart's content without having to install any software on your PC.  I'd recommend [Puppy Linux](http://www.puppylinux.org/) if you took that approach.

Alternatively, you could install a virtualisation product (like [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/)) and create a Linux VM.  In that case, I'd suggest using Ubuntu.

My experience is that either the live distro or VM approach would be better than using Cygwin as a development environment.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get the exact same performance.  But whether this is a drawback or not depends on what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Few more things to understand:

**GCC-Cygwin:**

Pros -

1. Compiling C code using gcc under cygwin would generate a windows executable, which uses the cygwin.dll(Posix emulation layer) linked dynamically into your app/code. So if you need to execute this app from some other path or other windows machine, that should have cygwin installed and in its path  else you get error.
2. Cygwin provides a benefit in that, if you have a POSIX compliant code developed on Linux-gcc you can compile it with no changes at all(very little changes in some case) on windows. So it kind of provides Posix compatibility on windows.

Cons -

1. If you are going to run some which is going to consume heavy system resources(memory,CPU) then not sure how cygwin would scale up as compared to a native executable on Linux.
2. Sometimes, Debugging using ddd on cygwin, I have found some weird crashes/hang of the ddd.

**GCC-Linux:**

1. If your final app is going to be executing on Linux, it makes sense to compile, and debug it under the same environment. Linux-gcc.
2. For Debugging , linux would provide you lot of tools (gdb/ddd, valgrind), etc.
3. If you want to accelerate some critical protion of code, using inline assembly with gcc under linux is nicely defined and has no issues working.(Udner Cygwin, i have faced sometimes that getting a inline assembly compiled was a problem)
4. If you want to add multiple threads for execution on multiple processors/cores, then pthreads comes to your help(Not sure about the same udner cygwin)